# How to fix the exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B while getting the objctGUID from AD?

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to fetch an unique identifier from windows AD. But at the following line of code:

```
byte[] objGUIDByteArr = (byte[]) attrs.get("objectGUID").get();
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
```

How to fix this & get the `byte[]` value from the objectGUID?

Comment: what is `attrs` ?

Comment: `javax.naming.directory.Attributes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must pass a base environment property to let spring LDAP know that `objectGUID` has to be returned in `java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary` format instead of the default `String` format.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your attribute object's actual type is `String`.

Proper way to convert String to byte array and back:

```
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attributes as = new BasicAttributes("a1", "val1");
        try {
            String attribute = (String) Optional.ofNullable(as.get("a1"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No such attribute"))
                    .get();
            byte[] objGUIDByteArr = attribute.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(new String(objGUIDByteArr));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
val1
```

According to documentation you can get `null`, so I you should add null-handling to avoid NPE (That's why I added `Optional` for additional check which is available starting from java 8):

```
/**
  * Retrieves the attribute with the given attribute id from the
  * attribute set.
  *
  * @param attrID The non-null id of the attribute to retrieve.
  *           If this attribute set ignores the character
  *           case of its attribute ids, the case of attrID
  *           is ignored.
  * @return The attribute identified by attrID; null if not found.
  * @see #put
  * @see #remove
  */
Attribute get(String attrID);
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Converting it to string changes the `byte[]` value and hence the final `objectGUID` value in the string format.

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that attribute instance has value other than GUID. This may happen due to multiple issues with AD (errors during synchronization with other LDAP directory services).
Just use `try/catch` to handle this problem.